# Why am I getting a java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError when trying to run my Java GUI from a jar file?

Tags: java, java-20

I am using VSCode to create a Java GUI (that is connected to a SQL Server Database). Everything runs when I run it using VSCode's Java Project system, however, when I try to convert it to a jar file, I get this error:

> Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class App
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Preview features are not enabled for App (class file version 64.65535). Try running with '--enable-preview'

When I run it with `--enable-preview`, it works. However, I need to make it work permanently on the jar (when I double click)

App is the name of my 'Main' class

My current java version:

```
java -version
java version "20" 2023-03-21
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20+36-2344)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20+36-2344, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Note: I am using a Mac and NO build tools (like Maven/Gradle etc.)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What GUI library are you using?

Comment: I'm using swing (jFrame, jTextArea etc.)

Comment: I tried this, but got the same error

Comment: Edit your Question to have those additional details.

Comment: By the way… Preview features are *not* meant to be deployed. Thus the label "preview". See https://openjdk.org/jeps/12 and https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/language/preview-language-and-vm-features.html

Comment: Are you using a preview feature in your code? You might need to share the code, and the command used to compile.

Comment: Maybe you can try using a IDE that is more towards Java developing. For example NetBeans, IntelliJ, Eclipse ,... . They have GUI builder-tools inside them. That makes problem solving a little bit easier. -> That's a more general answer.

Comment: It is working now. I just had to add a .settings file with org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enablePreviewFeatures=disabled.
However, my jar still won't open on double click only through command line

Answer (score 1):

It is working now. I just had to add a .settings folder that contains a file with org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler.problem.enablePreviewFeatures=disabled.